# Same data routine "CalcPrecio" works fine called from a button, but breaks when called from a Canvas event, in Lightswitch HTML client

Tags: events, canvas, visual-studio-lightswitch, jscript

This is jscript over Lightswitch HTML Client
Same routine Works fine called from a Button, but fails when called from a Canvas event, showing an undefined data error.

```
// Creates a Canvas and add an eventlistner Works fine

myapp.AddEditLito.Montajes_render = function (element, contentItem) {
var itemTemplate = $("<canvas id='myCanvas' width='600' height='150'></canvas>");

    var canvas = myCanvas;
    myCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    DibTriangulo(screen, 50); // Draws a triangle, everything fine until here

    // here is the problem, 
    CalcPrecio(screen, 1); // breaks with "Undefined Data.. etc."
    }, false);
};

// Called from a Button, same routine works perfect!!

myapp.AddEditLito.Button1_execute = function (screen) { 
    CalcPrecio(screen, 1); // Works fine
};

// This routine Works perfect called from a button, but fails when called from a Canvas event!

function CalcPrecio(screen, col) {
    $.each(screen.Liquidas.data, function (i, p) {
        p.valor = p.cantidad * p.unitario;
    });
};
```

//What I´m doing wrong? Heeeelp!

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a result of calling your DibTriangulo and CalcPrecio routines from your canvas' mousedown event handler with just screen as the first parameter.

In your mousedown event handler and the _render [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) it's defined in, the screen object is not specifically set to refer to the LightSwitch screen instance and instead simply refers to the [window.screen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/screen) object.

To resolve this you can simply change your code to use contentItem.screen as shown in the following revised _render method:

```
myapp.AddEditLito.Montajes_render = function (element, contentItem) {
    var itemTemplate = $("<canvas id='myCanvas' width='600' height='150'></canvas>");

    var canvas = myCanvas;
    myCanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        DibTriangulo(contentItem.screen, 50); // Changed to pass in contentItem.screen

        CalcPrecio(contentItem.screen, 1); // Changed to pass in contentItem.screen
    }, false);
};
```

The reason using just screen works in your button's _execute method is because the _execute method receives the LightSwitch screen object as its parameter (which you then use when calling your CalcPrecio method).